# Buffer size Issue

Tags: c

I wrote a C program that calls a Unix Script. The script writes output to a file that is read through the POPEN command.

While reading the output, which is 20+ characters (e.g. "452088000104023512234"), through existing code it gets converted to some junk characters.

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

#define  OUTPUT_FILE_PATH  "/td/mbb/Projects/MBNA/Work/java.txt"
#define  SCRIPT_FILE_PATH  "/td/mbb/Projects/MBNA/Work/R/TDEncryptDecrypt/TDEncryptDecrypt/src/java.sh"

void waitAndExecuteScript(char* input)
{
    char scriptCmd[256];
    sprintf(scriptCmd, "%s  %s", SCRIPT_FILE_PATH, input);   

    int i = system(scriptCmd);  //execute command string

    FILE* fp = fopen ( OUTPUT_FILE_PATH , "rb" );

    while (1)
    {
        if(fp == NULL)
        {
            usleep(1000);
            fp = fopen (OUTPUT_FILE_PATH , "rb" );
        }
        else
        {
            fclose(fp);
            break;
        }
    }
}

char * java (char* str1)
{
    int i,l;
    char * resultval;
    char * buffer = NULL;
    long lSize = 0;
    size_t result = 0;
    FILE* pFile = NULL;
    char  removeCmd[256];

    waitAndExecuteScript(str1);

    //******************************reading input data in a file ************************

    pFile = fopen (OUTPUT_FILE_PATH , "rb" );
    if (pFile==NULL)
    {
        fputs ("File error",stderr);
        exit (1);
    }

    // obtain file size:
    fseek (pFile , 0 , SEEK_END);
    lSize = ftell (pFile);
    rewind (pFile);

    // allocate memory to contain the whole file:
    buffer = (char*) malloc (sizeof(char)*lSize + 1);   // 1 extra byte need to allocate to accomodate null character
    if (buffer == NULL)
    {
        fputs ("Memory error",stderr);
        exit (2);
    }

    // copy the file into the buffer:
    result = fread (buffer,1,lSize,pFile);
    if (result != lSize)
    {
        fputs ("Reading error",stderr);
        exit (3);
    }

    /* the whole file is now loaded in the memory buffer. */

    buffer[lSize] = '\0';                //make string null terminated so that printf will print it properly
    printf("result from script %s", buffer);

    resultval = buffer;    
    // terminate
    fclose (pFile);
    if(buffer != NULL)
    {
        free (buffer);
    }

    //wait here for 1ms 
    usleep(1000);

    return resultval;  //Return the result value of the script
}
```

Comment: 1. Looks like C, not C++ 2. where do you actually *read* from `fp`?

Comment: Retagged as C, you'll get better help this way.

Comment: Have you verified that the file you're reading actually contains text?

Comment: Yes I have verified file on Unix it is actually containing same value as "452088000104023512234"

Comment: Is this some attempt at working around having to implement io-pipe-redirection? Regardless. How about checking the results of [`fseek`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fseek) before assuming it worked.

Comment: Either don't cast `malloc` `buffer = (char*) malloc (sizeof(char)*lSize + 1)` or don't use a c++ compiler for compiling c code so you don't need to cast it.

Comment: I have to use C++ compiler ... what will be alternative way to declare malloc buffer = (char*) malloc (sizeof(char)*lSize + 1)

Comment: @Vibhor If you actually *want* to write C++, use `std::string` for strings, `iostreams`, etc. If this is a text file, then reading into a `std::string` requires no dynamic allocation, but if you really need it, `new` should generally be used in C++ (along with `delete []` for arrays).

Comment: @Crashmstr  Thx for your valuable inputs. Can you plz modify my existing code as i didn't get completely modification you suggested. As i am new to C++ coding :)

Answer (score 3):

What you appear to be doing is:

1. Running some external command to write to a file
2. Polling to see whether you can open the file (that's in `waitAndExecuteScript`)
3. Immediately afterwards, reading the file (that's in `java`).

This strategy will not work. Unless you know that the external command creates the file atomically (e.g. by writing it to a different file then renaming it), the file will exist and become readable before it is fully written. Consider the following ordering:

1. External process opens the file for writing, but writes nothing yet
2. `waitAndExecuteScript` successfully opens the empty file
3. `java` reads the empty file
4. External process writes data.

As you can see, the data may be partially written.

What you should do is check that the process that is doing the writing has completed. Alternatively, make it write to a pipe and use blocking reads.

Comment: File is getting created ... and correct data is also getting written to file on Unix box i have verified that ... only issue which i am facing is that .. when no of characters are less output is coming correctly but when no of characters in file is getting exceeded up to 20 it is not reading properly ... it seems like some Buffer size  issue .

Comment: if you'd do what you said you are doing (reading the stdout of a forked process using `popen()`) instead of taking the sole existence of the file as a finished answer, your program would (#1) work and (#2) would be easier to understand.

Comment: @mfro I took it to mean that the script was reading its input using `popen` and writing its output to a file - i.e. the output of the script is using a temporary file to get rid of the deadlock and programming issues involved in creating two pipes. But I may be wrong.

Answer (score 1):

Your memory management is also flawed:

```
resultval = buffer;    
...
if(buffer != NULL)
{
    free (buffer);
}
...
return resultval;  //Return the result value of the script
```

`resultval = buffer` makes a pointer variable `resultval` points to the same location as `buffer` points.  But then you `free()`-ed the memory chunk which is located there.  So `resultval` points to an invalid memory location when you return it from your `java()` function.

If your platform is Linux, I'd recommend you to install and use the Valgrind memory debugger to easily spot bugs like this.

- http://valgrind.org/docs/manual/quick-start.html

Comment: Sorry i can't install "Valgrind memory debugger" as it requires many approvals and it will delay my work. Please suggest what will be correct way to handle this memory issue ?? Its seems you are correct.

Comment: Suggest me if i don't free space then it will create any issue ..??

Comment: Because you didn't show how to use your `java()` function, I can give you only a broad advice: move `free(buffer)` from inside `java()` to just after the last usage of the return value of `java()`.  If you simply remove `free(buffer)`, you will end up with memory leak (which, in some rare cases, is regarded as an "acceptable" bug.)

Comment: Please confirm if my understanding is correct i should free space after return function ....this is what you are trying to explain.

Comment: Not quite true.  Right after returning from your `java()` function is not a right place to call `free()`.  There must be other code reading the returned data from `java()` (but you didn't show how you read it.)  You should call `free()` after that.